# Custom rules Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, rules

I have a question about Alfresco.

My goal is to apply a rule to a folder. It will change the name of the father of a file tree of folders.
For this, I would go through a webscript that retrieve the parent directory and then change his name.
The problem is I'm totally newbie on Alfresco, I do not know how to do it and what to put in my webscript.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a rule on a folder to do this, you don't need a web script at all, you simply use the JavaScript API. You can use the JavaScript API to traverse up the tree and do the rename. Go read [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/API-JS-intro.html), try writing the rule, and if you can't figure it out come back with a specific question that you are having problems with.

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Go on the Alfresco backoffice and place an new script in company home/data dictionary/scripts folder. The script must have 'JavaScript' type...

Go on any folder, manage rules and create a new rule which execute script... The script can be trigger on a 'new file' event, 'update' or 'remove'...

Hope this help you !